# generate hibernate.reveng.xml file in intellij IDEA

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

Is there an automatic way to generate the hibernate.reveng.xml file in Intellij IDEA?

I couldn't find any way of doing this, in this [link](https://www.codejava.net/frameworks/hibernate/how-to-customize-hibernate-reverse-engineering-code-generation) I saw how to generate it outside of Intellij.

I guess I am not the first one to encounter this problem, but i didn't saw any answers on this subject, if there is a plugin to Intellij that make it, or a simple way to generate it inside Intellij it would help alot.

Also, if it isn't currently available, knowing this will also help.

Thanks ahead

edit:

Found [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-128307?_ga=2.177835047.34013903.1607929835-1780415510.1603705196) ticket, but I didn't understand how to do it...

Answer (score 0):

There is no action to generate Hibernate reveng.xml file in IntelliJ IDEA. Feel free to create such [request](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA&c=Type%20Feature&c=Subsystem%20Frameworks.%20Hibernate&c=Assignee%20sergeyv).

Comment: i did [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-257809?c=Type%20Feature&c=Subsystem%20Frameworks.%20Hibernate&c=Assignee%20sergeyv) thanks for the idea